# share a zip file on bluetooth

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, zip, share

I have a Zip file has been created in my app, and now I want to share this zip file on other apps in android phone like Bluetooth or Gmail or ... .
I used this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, zipName);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,activity.getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

that the zipname is my zip file path.
this code is executed by pushing a button. a list will popup with all the apps, but by clicking on Bluetooth just the popup will close and nothing else!

why? please help me. I need the Bluetooth open up and make the Bluetooth turned on ,....

Comment: is the file zipname present? do other apps have access to the file?

Comment: yes the zip-file exists and this file is on sdcard on a folder, I think this is accessible. how to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solve it myself, zipname was the path to file but it needs to be uri so I have use thi code

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri.fromfile(new File(zipName)));
```

instead of

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, zipName);
```